# FPDF table cells margin and rounded corners

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, rounded-corners

I am working on the creating PDF report files with tables.

And I need to have margin between each table cell and rounded corners for each cell also. Something like this: http://joxi.net/L21XyyLh8aRnLm

Is there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This script from fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script7.php) is capable of drawing rounded rectangles. Let's extend it to add a `$cellspacing` variable:

```
<?php
require('rounded_rect.php');

class Bohdan_PDF extends PDF {
    var $cellspacing = 1;

    function SetCellspacing($cellspacing) {
        $this->cellspacing = $cellspacing;
    }
```

Next, let's add a method which outputs a cell, drawing a rounded rectangle around it, and adding the cellspacing. It should accept the same arguments as `Cell` except for `$border`.

```
    function RoundedBorderCell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $ln=0, $align='',
            $fill=false, $link='') {
        $this->RoundedRect($this->getX() + $this->cellspacing / 2,
            $this->getY() + $this->cellspacing / 2,
            $w - $this->cellspacing, $h, 1, 'DF');
        $this->Cell($w, $h + $this->cellspacing, $txt, $ln, 0, $align,
            $fill, $link);
    }
```

The following method takes care of outputting the table.

```
    function BohdanTable($header, $data, $widths, $aligns) {
        $this->SetLineWidth(0.15);
        $rowHeight = $this->FontSizePt - 2;

        $this->SetFillColor(255, 255, 0);
        for ($i = 0, $j = sizeof($header); $i < $j; $i++) {
            $this->RoundedBorderCell($widths[$i], $rowHeight,
                $header[$i], 0, $aligns[$i]);
        }
        $this->Ln();

        foreach ($data as $rowId => $row) {
            $this->SetFillColor($rowId % 2 == 1 ? 240 : 255);
            for ($i = 0, $j = sizeof($row); $i < $j; $i++) {
                $this->RoundedBorderCell($widths[$i], $rowHeight,
                    $row[$i], 0, $aligns[$i]);
            }
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$pdf = new Bohdan_PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 9);
$pdf->BohdanTable(array_fill(0, 4, "Building Name"),
    array(
        array("Administration Building", "46,314", "1,471,818", "4%"),
        array("Alumni House", "4,939", "1,471,818", "400%"),
        array("Alumni House Garage", "347", "1,471,818", "34%"),
        array("Alumni House Garden House", "165", "1,471,818", "16%")
    ),
    array(105, 26, 26, 26),
    array('L', 'R', 'R', 'R'));
$pdf->Output();
```

Example output:

[image: Example output]

#### Update

This fixes the page break problem described in the comments. This code checks if there is enough space left on the current page to add the next row, and if there isn't, it puts the row on a new page.

```
    function RoundedBorderCell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $ln=0, $align='',
            $fill=false, $link='') {
        $spaceLeft = ($this->h - $this->getY() - $this->bMargin);
        $cellHeight = $h + $this->cellspacing;
        if ($spaceLeft < $cellHeight) {
            $this->AddPage();
        }
        $this->RoundedRect($this->getX() + $this->cellspacing / 2,
            $this->getY() + $this->cellspacing / 2,
            $w - $this->cellspacing, $h, 1, 'DF');
        $this->Cell($w, $cellHeight, $txt, $ln, 0, $align, $fill, $link);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Matthias, this is exactly what i was looking for. Just perfect solution.

Comment: For some reason last element on the page not shifting to the second page. This is continuing on every page. How can I fix it? http://joxi.net/KAgPppKs4V9nxr

Comment: Thanks again Matthias, this is wokrs exactly like i need it. You helped me to save tons of time.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Matthias can you please help me with header structure crating as on the sreenshot http://joxi.net/nAybVVzuYWqGvr , but with the same way as we did with rounded corners.
Thanks

Comment: Bohdan: I think it would be best to repost this as a fresh question. First, this is not directly related to your original question, and second, your question won't get seen by many people here. Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question.

Comment: Matthias: I have created new post about my question, here is link to the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049985/fpdf-create-pdf-with-tree-level-table-header-structure-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 0):

This is ported to **Python 3**.
Thanks to *Christophe Prugnaud* and *Maxime Delorme* and *Matthias Wiehl* for the original code.

```py
from fpdf import FPDF
import math

class ROUND_PDF(FPDF):
    def rounded_cell(self, w, h=0, txt='', border=0, ln=0, align='', fill=False, link='', radius = 1, corners =  (1,2,3,4), cellspacing = 1):
        style = 'S'
        if fill and border:
            style = 'FD'
        elif fill:
            style = 'F'
        self.rounded_rect(self.get_x() + (cellspacing / 2.0), 
            self.get_y() +  (cellspacing / 2.0),
            w - cellspacing, h, radius, corners, style)
        self.cell(w, h + cellspacing, txt, 0, ln, align, False, link)

    def rounded_rect(self, x, y, w, h, r, corners = (1,2,3,4), style = ''):
        k = self.k
        hp = self.h
        if style == 'F':
            op = 'f'
        elif style=='FD' or style == 'DF':
            op='B'
        else:
            op='S'
        my_arc = 4/3 * (math.sqrt(2) - 1)
        self._out('%.2F %.2F m' % ((x+r)*k,(hp-y)*k ))
        xc = x+w-r 
        yc = y+r
        self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % (xc*k,(hp-y)*k ))
        if 2 not in corners:
            self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % ((x+w)*k,(hp-y)*k ))
        else:
            self._arc(xc + r*my_arc, yc - r, xc + r, yc - r*my_arc, xc + r, yc)
        xc = x+w-r
        yc = y+h-r
        self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % ((x+w)*k,(hp-yc)*k))
        if 3 not in corners:
            self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % ((x+w)*k,(hp-(y+h))*k))
        else:
            self._arc(xc + r, yc + r*my_arc, xc + r*my_arc, yc + r, xc, yc + r)
        xc = x+r
        yc = y+h-r
        self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % (xc*k,(hp-(y+h))*k))
        if 4 not in corners:
            self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % ((x)*k,(hp-(y+h))*k))
        else:
            self._arc(xc - r*my_arc, yc + r, xc - r, yc + r*my_arc, xc - r, yc)
        xc = x+r
        yc = y+r
        self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % ((x)*k,(hp-yc)*k ))
        if 1 not in corners:
            self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % ((x)*k,(hp-y)*k ))
            self._out('%.2F %.2F l' % ((x+r)*k,(hp-y)*k ))
        else:
            self._arc(xc - r, yc - r*my_arc, xc - r*my_arc, yc - r, xc, yc - r)
        self._out(op)

    def _arc(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
        h = self.h
        self._out('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F c ' % (x1*self.k, (h-y1)*self.k,x2*self.k, (h-y2)*self.k, x3*self.k, (h-y3)*self.k))
```