# FPDF, create PDF with tree level table header structure with rounded corners

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I need to create a PDF file with table with rounded corners.

I have pdf file with table like this:

[image]

And I need to create table with header like on this image:

[image]

I already have done work on the table main content and footer structure. It is already with rounded corners.

Just having hard time with creating table header with this kind of structure.

Comment: Have you check this [question]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652606/fpdf-table-cells-margin-and-rounded-corners?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: Yes, this my question too. But Matthias Wiehl suggested to me to open new post because this is little bit of topic on previous. 
So this question is basically is continuing from the previous post.
In comment you can see the link leading to this post.

Comment: If a commercial solution is an option, maybe try to use typeset.sh for this. (bias)